# what is the most efficient(battery) way to repeat an action in android?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, repeat

I searched all stack-overflow and Google and I found that their is couple of ways to do it.
The best and most suitable way that I found is Alarmmanger. But I think that it consumes the battery cause I use it with RTC_Wakeup.

My app runs the function every defined time (it can be 1 min till 1 hour, User choice).
The function needs to run even if the app dosen't.

What the best way to do without consuming a lot of battery power?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AlarmManager is really the best option for you. You clearly need a service to trigger your app on, as you want your action to execute when your app is not launched. The only way to achieve this is a pending intent and alarm managers barely does anything else than handling pending intents.

Comment: But correct me if I'm wrong but if I have an alarm manager that accrues every 15 min it means that every 15 min the phone wakes up and it consumes a lot of battery power...? 
On the other hand for example their is phone wifi that in case it turned on it scans for wifi spot every couple of minutes and it doesn't consume so much power. How do they do it?

Comment: You should try to measure something. Everything is too fuzzy right now and everything can be said.